# Testing difference in means for two bimodal distributions?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I have two bimodal distributions of data with two peaks (one around 0 and the other around 1). I have provided an example of one of the distributions.
[image]
Although their means and variances are different, they both have peaks around the same x-axis markers. How do I test for difference in means using statistically rigorous approaches? Can I still use a t-test even though the data is not normally distributed?

Comment: What exactly is your testing question? What are you trying to determine -- whether the two are the same vs. different?

Comment: Yeah. If one of the means if 0.55 and the other is 0.45, what approach do I use to determine if they are different using a statistical approach (other than visualizing, comparing means, etc.)

Comment: I have a pointer to a paper solving this problem (namely, testing $p=q$ vs. $d(p,q)> \varepsilon$ using an order-optimal number of samples, when $p,q$ are assumed to be *discrete* bimodal distributions), if you want. Where $d$ refers to the total variation/statistical distance. (Though I believe it actually also works for continuous ones (?) over $[0,1]$.)

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7354450 (free version on the authors' website or arxiv: https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~dakane/closeness-structured.pdf)

Comment: Cross post : https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/383507/119261.